# C# Break out of foreach loop after X number of items

Tags: c#, foreach

In my foreach loop I would like to stop after 50 items, how would you break out of this foreach loop when I reach the 50th item?

Thanks

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items)
```

Comment: @Jade, I don't mean to disrespect Hamish, but I seriously think that you have accepted the wrong answer. If you know up front how many iterations of a loop you want to perform, there is a language construct specific to that, and that's a for loop. Breaking out of a foreach is not a bad thing, so Hamish's answer is not wrong...but as a typical rule of thumb if you can avoid Jumps (and that is what a break is) you should. I don't mean write convoluted code to avoid breaks, breaks sometimes are the best option, but in this case the most deterministic is a simple for loop.

Comment: @Tim Jarvis, I don't think you're disrespecting me. What you are saying (and it's a valid response to the question) is that @Jade M is asking the wrong question. Rather than "How do I break out of a foreach loop?" the real question is "What iterative code construct should I use if I want to iterate for a known maximum of iterations?"

Comment: @Hamish, mmm, yep you are correct, that's it in a nutshell.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
int processed = 0;
foreach(ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items)
{
   //do stuff
   if (++processed == 50) break;
}
```

or use LINQ

```
foreach( ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Take(50))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

or just use a regular for loop (as suggested by @sgriffinusa and @Eric J.)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50 && i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = listView.Items[i];
}
```

Comment: The ListViewItemCollection does not have an implementaion of Take() defined. Your example above won't compile.

You could probably do something like theListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Take(50) but I think that a simple for loop would be much more performent.

Comment: ListViewItemCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable<T>, can't use LINQ

Comment: Enumerable.Cast<T> fixes that up : The Cast<(Of <(TResult>)>)(IEnumerable) method enables the standard query operators to be invoked on non-generic collections by supplying the necessary type information. For example,  ArrayList does not implement IEnumerable<(Of <(T>)>) , but by calling Cast<(Of <(TResult>)>)(IEnumerable) on the  ArrayList object, the standard query operators can then be used to query the sequence.

Answer (score 24):

Why not just use a regular for loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50 && i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = listView.Items[i];
}
```

Updated to resolve bug pointed out by Ruben and Pragmatrix.

Comment: if (listView.Items.Count < 50) throw new OutOfRangeException();

Answer (score 7):

Or just use a regular for loop instead of foreach.  A for loop is slightly faster (though you won't notice the difference except in very time critical code).

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

```
int i = 1;
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items) {
    ...
    if(++i == 50) break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int count = 0;
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items)
{
    if(++count > 50) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **break**, like that:

```
int cont = 0;
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items) {
   if(cont==50) { //if listViewItem reach 50 break out.
      break; 
   }
   cont++;   //increment cont.
}
```